# How can I solve this equation: $xe^{ax}=b$?

Tags: exponential-function

How can I solve this type of equation?
$xe^{ax}=b$?

Comment: Use the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+Exp[a+x]%3Db

Answer (score 1):

For most values of $a$ and $b$ there is no solution in terms of "elementary functions", i.e. you can rearrange to get $x$ on its own using just algebra and the functions that you learned about in school.

One way would be to use numerical methods, e.g. [interval bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_as_approximation), etc.

Another way would be to use a function called [Lambert's W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). This is a very exotic function. It is *defined* to be the inverse of $z \mapsto z\mathrm e^z$. You will probably need a computer programme - I've never found a calculator with this function - to make any calculations.

There are [lots of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples) of the W-funtion's application on Wikipedia.

Personally, in my humble opinion, using the W-function feels like cheating. I'd use a numerical method. After all, and answer in terms of the W-function, say $\mathrm W(5)$ is meaningless to a human being and we'd need to ask a computer to give a decimal approximation anyway.

Comment: Why is $W(5)$ more meaningless than, say, $\ln(5)$?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf As I said: it's my personal, humble opinion. The exponential functions $x \mapsto A\mathrm e^{bx}$ make sense to me in terms of real world examples, e.g. continuously compounded interest, approximating nuclear decay or bacteria growth. The natural logarithm is the inverse of a function that I know well. Moreover, I can estimate $\ln x$ in my head to at least the same order of magnitude. I don't know of - although I'm sure there are - real world applications of the W-function, and I can't estimate it, even with a pen and paper.